How to make ERB or ERUBI escape HTML in the template without escaping the entire template - NOT RAILS
I'm using ERB or ERUB or Tilt here outside of Rails and I want to make my HTML templates work like rails where stuff is HTML escaped by default.
e.g.
<!-- file.html.erb -->
<h1>Hello <%= name %></h1>

When I render this, if name is <b>Pat</b>, then the HTML sent to the browser is:
<h1>Hello <b>Pat</b></h1>

I'd like it to render this:
<h1>Hello &lt;b&gt;Pat&lt;/b&gt;</h1>

And I'd like that behavior to be the default anytime <%=  is used.
I'm trying Tilt, but when I do Tilt.new("file.html.erb",escape_html: true) it escapes the entire file, rendering &lt;h1&gt;Hello &lt;b&gt;Pat&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/h1&gt;
I tried reading Rails' source to figure this out, but it's highly abstracted and wondering if anyone reading this happens to know how to achieve this.

are you sure? Tilt.new("file.html.erb", escape_html: true).render #=> "<h1>Hello &lt;b&gt;name&lt;/b&gt;</h1>\n"

When running Tilt.new("file.html.erb", escape_html: true).render(nil, name: '<b>Pat</b>'), I get your expected result. Please edit your question to show a full (self-contained) example demonstrating your issue. Likely, you are just integrating it weird or have some subsequent escaping step...

Answering my own question -> Erubi and Tilt + Erbui does actually work the way I want, but my problem was in using yield to create a layout-style nested set of templates.
In the most basic case, things work:
<!-- outer.html.erb -->
<h1>Hello! <%= name %></h1>

require "tilt"

name = "<b>Pat</b>"

template = Tilt.new("outer.html.erb",
                    engine: Erubi::Engine,
                    escape_html: true)
s = template.render(self, name: name)
puts s

produces:
<h1>Hello! &lt;b&gt;Pat&lt;/b&gt;</h1>

What I was trying to do, which I omitted from the question because I thought I was simplifying, was to do a layout-style nested template setup.
<!-- inner.html.erb -->
<h2>Yup <%= name %></h2>

<!-- outer.html.erb -->
<h1>Hello! <%= name %></h1>

<%= yield %>

require "tilt"

name = "<b>Pat</b>"

inner = Tilt.new("inner.html.erb",
                 engine: Erubi::Engine,                  
                 escape_html: true)
rendered_inner = inner.render(self, name: name)

template = Tilt.new("outer.html.erb",
                    engine: Erubi::Engine,
                    escape_html: true)
s = template.render(self, name: name) do
  rendered_inner
end
puts s

Because I'm yielding a string containing HTML to render, I get the HTML escaped when I didn't want it to:
<h1>Hello! &lt;b&gt;Pat&lt;/b&gt;</h1>
&lt;h2&gt;Yup &amp;lt;b&amp;gt;Pat&amp;lt;/b&amp;gt;&lt;/h2&gt;

To me, it appeared as if escape_html: was escaping everything.
The solution is to use <%== in outer.html.erb:
<!-- outer.html.erb -->
<h1>Hello! <%= name %></h1>
<%== yield %>

Which does what I want:
<h1>Hello! &lt;b&gt;Pat&lt;/b&gt;</h1>
<h2>Yup &lt;b&gt;Pat&lt;/b&gt;</h2>

Whew!
Of course, omitted escape_html: true does not escape by default.
